# How to use mode() on resampling timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has timeseries, with each data corresponds to a day_of_week (monday to sunday)

I am interested to know when my timeseries convert to a monthly basis, what's the day_of_week that appears the most frequent for each month and I use the following:

```
bike['days_of_the_week'].resample('M').mode()
```

But this gave me error

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'mode'

So 'mode' doesn't work with timeseries? Then what's the best possible way to figure out the "mode" question after resample?

Comment: Hey @ZhenMa, any feedback on the answer? Hope it helped!

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for [pd.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), you can use `apply` to pass a custom resampler. SciPy has an implementation you can use, [scipy.stats.mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html), with a bit of adaptation.

```
import scipy.stats

def mode(xs):
    return scipy.stats.mode(xs)[0][0]
```

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

days = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
bike = pd.DataFrame({'days_of_the_week': days.weekday_name}, index=days) 

bike['days_of_the_week'].resample('M').apply(mode)
# 2019-01-31    Thursday
# 2019-02-28      Friday
# 2019-03-31      Friday
# 2019-04-30      Monday
# 2019-05-31      Friday
# 2019-06-30    Saturday
# 2019-07-31      Monday
# 2019-08-31      Friday
# 2019-09-30      Monday
# 2019-10-31    Thursday
# 2019-11-30      Friday
# 2019-12-31      Monday
# Freq: M, Name: days_of_the_week, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @mcskinner works in most of the case, but I would recommend error catching in case the dataframe is not continuous to avoid IndexError

```
from scipy import stats
def mode(xs):
    try:
        return stats.mode(xs)[0][0]
    except IndexError:
        return np.nan
```